# How can I plot a list of 1-D data along the x-axis?

Tags: plotting

I would like to know how to create a graph from the following data:

```
{4.958,4.868,4.894,4.94,4.93,4.896,4.856,4.8,4.94,4 4.874,4.876,4.858,
4.842,4.986,4.84,4.838,4.88,4.96,4.914,4.806,4.984,4.956,4.808,4.914,
4.922,4.854,4.876,4.996,4.834,4.922,4.89,4.912,4.786,4.852,4.93,4.87,
4.936,4.968,4.988,4.924,5.004,4.94,4.936,4.856,4.928,4.994,4.992,4.95,
4.916,4.862,4.876,4.91,4.864,4.89,4.908,4.846,4.89,4.962,4.908,4.846,
4.966,4.928,4.852,4.962,4.874,4.898,4.93,4.968,4.912,4.924,4.994,4.902,
4.914,4.926,5.014,4.896,4.832,4.916,4.932,4.936,4.876,4.884,4.948,
4.864,5.07,4.9,5.236,4.884,4.972,4.986,4.932,4.936,4.866,5.094,4.904,
5.044,4.94,4.914,4.878,4.976,4.91,4.92,4.97,5.002,5.018,5.018,4.834,
4.972,4.98,4.882,5.05,4.936,4.97,4.974,4.932,5.022,4.978,4.95,4.952,
4.876,4.908,4.91,4.956,4.914,4.89,4.882,4.96,5.044,5.014,4.988,4.964,
4.904,4.928,4.984,4.932,5.092,5.042,4.954,5,4.93,5.008,4.984,5.052,
4.99,5.008,5.034,5.042,5.042,4.986,5.026,4.88,4.948,5.014,5.14,4.94,
4.984,5.032,4.97,5.06,5.058,5.068,4.948,4.954,5.138,5.032,5.02,4.928,
4.98,5.122,4.9,4.95,5.02,4.978,5.008,5.03,5.104,5.054,5.062,4.928,
5.094,4.97,5.024,5.004,5.016,5.036,5.026,5.038,5.01,5.002,5.116,4.976,
5.052,4.88,5.094,5.082,4.996,5.122,5.034,5.07,5.054}
```

These data should represent positions along the x-axis, and the y-axis should take on values from 1 to 200.

Comment: This is quite a basic question. It will be better to show what you've already tried so others may help you to understand how to solve _your_ problems

Comment: If you google for "mathematica plot data", you'll find several pages describing how to do this.  Have you searched before asking?

Comment: @Jakob Akkerboom: Your edit changed `4, 4.874` to `4 4.874`. What were you intending to do?

Comment: If you do not want to show the data development over time you might consider `Histogram[ data, number of data points ]` which will also show the outliers that might be hidden in Plot-derivatices?

Answer (score 4):

This is straightforward.

Your data:

```
datax = {4.958, 4.868, 4.894, 4.94, 4.93, 4.896, 4.856, 4.8, 4.94, 
   4 4.874, 4.876, 4.858, 4.842, 4.986, 4.84, 4.838, 4.88, 4.96, 
   4.914, 4.806, 4.984, 4.956, 4.808, 4.914, 4.922, 4.854, 4.876, 
   4.996, 4.834, 4.922, 4.89, 4.912, 4.786, 4.852, 4.93, 4.87, 4.936, 
   4.968, 4.988, 4.924, 5.004, 4.94, 4.936, 4.856, 4.928, 4.994, 
   4.992, 4.95, 4.916, 4.862, 4.876, 4.91, 4.864, 4.89, 4.908, 4.846, 
   4.89, 4.962, 4.908, 4.846, 4.966, 4.928, 4.852, 4.962, 4.874, 
   4.898, 4.93, 4.968, 4.912, 4.924, 4.994, 4.902, 4.914, 4.926, 
   5.014, 4.896, 4.832, 4.916, 4.932, 4.936, 4.876, 4.884, 4.948, 
   4.864, 5.07, 4.9, 5.236, 4.884, 4.972, 4.986, 4.932, 4.936, 4.866, 
   5.094, 4.904, 5.044, 4.94, 4.914, 4.878, 4.976, 4.91, 4.92, 4.97, 
   5.002, 5.018, 5.018, 4.834, 4.972, 4.98, 4.882, 5.05, 4.936, 4.97, 
   4.974, 4.932, 5.022, 4.978, 4.95, 4.952, 4.876, 4.908, 4.91, 4.956,
    4.914, 4.89, 4.882, 4.96, 5.044, 5.014, 4.988, 4.964, 4.904, 
   4.928, 4.984, 4.932, 5.092, 5.042, 4.954, 5, 4.93, 5.008, 4.984, 
   5.052, 4.99, 5.008, 5.034, 5.042, 5.042, 4.986, 5.026, 4.88, 4.948,
    5.014, 5.14, 4.94, 4.984, 5.032, 4.97, 5.06, 5.058, 5.068, 4.948, 
   4.954, 5.138, 5.032, 5.02, 4.928, 4.98, 5.122, 4.9, 4.95, 5.02, 
   4.978, 5.008, 5.03, 5.104, 5.054, 5.062, 4.928, 5.094, 4.97, 5.024,
    5.004, 5.016, 5.036, 5.026, 5.038, 5.01, 5.002, 5.116, 4.976, 
   5.052, 4.88, 5.094, 5.082, 4.996, 5.122, 5.034, 5.07, 5.054};
```

Your data as x-components, y-component is n = 1..Length[datax]:

```
data = Table[{datax[[n]],n}, {n, 1, Length[datax]}];
```

ListPlot it:

```
ListPlot[data]

(* graph not shown *)
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Why not `ListPlot@datax` directly?:-)

Comment: Or `Plot[Thread@{Range@Length[datax], datax}]`

Comment: @ ShutaoTang: because this would take the given values as y-coordinates instead of x-coordinates (as I did erroneously in my original code; please see my corrected code)

Comment: I understood the OP's intend on the contrary

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the docs for [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html?q=List), [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html?q=Table), and [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html?q=ListPlot) to get a handle on how Mathematica is set up to handle your data.

Your data is already formatted as a 1-D List, so it can be plotted directly by `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[data]
```

This will give you something like the following:

[image: listplot]

If you want your data plotted on the [abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa) with values from 1 to 200 for the ordinate (y-axis) value, you can make a 2D list with something like the following:

```
data2 = Partition[Riffle[data, Range[200]], 2];
```

In this case, `data2` can also be plotted directly, since `ListPlot` knows how to handle 2-D list input:

[image: data2 listplot]

---

One thing to note is that your data includes an outlier that is significantly larger than the rest of the set:

```
Max[data]
```

> (* 19.496 *)

```
Mean[data]
```

> (* 5.02909 *)

By default, ListPlot will try to show the range of your data that it thinks is interesting; this means that outliers aren't always visible unless you explicitly set the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html?q=PlotRange) option of ListPlot to All.